# Sending Data From One Page To The Other

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have a page in my website that contains a memberslist(a list of all my members) and I want to display the names of the top 5 posters (which is included on the memberslist page) on my home page.
How would I go about passing that data from my memberslist page to my home page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are referring to [Cross-Page posting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx) (by using the `PreviousPage` property of the Page you can accomplish it). Check [Microsoft's article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178139.aspx).

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Since HTTP is Stateless protocol. you can pass data via :

```
  1: Using QuerySdatring like  http://yourpageB?data1=1&data2=2
  and retrieve these values in second page.

 2. You can maintain session variables which takes help of cookies to store data in clients        machine and can be retrieved later.
```